# Get log from LoggerFactory

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

It is possible so simple, but I've wasted already a lot of time to find any solution.

I have

```
package net.rubyeye.xmemcached;

...
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...

public class XMemcachedClient implements XMemcachedClientMBean, MemcachedClient {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(XMemcachedClient.class);
....
```

With Log4j I get all logs from apache-servicemix.

I've tried something like

```
log4j.logger.net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient=All, xmemcachedLog

log4j.appender.xmemcachedLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.xmemcachedLog.File=${karaf.data}/log/spring/xmemcachedLog.log
log4j.appender.xmemcachedLog.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.xmemcachedLog.maxFileSize = 10MB
log4j.appender.xmemcachedLog.maxBackupIndex = 10
log4j.appender.xmemcachedLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.xmemcachedLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] - %m%n
```

But I don't get anything. I want to get information about exception which I get  on the 1335th line

```
key = this.preProcessKey(key);
```

Actually, it doesn't matter that I want to log exactly that class. In my application I also have other classes which have LoggerFactory.getLogger(...);

And the main question is 
How to get logs from **Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(SomeClass.class);**

Now, my rootLogger looks like

```
# Root logger 
log4j.rootLogger=info, out, sift, osgi:VmLogAppender 
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in my logger. I've just hadn't any log.error() or log.smth() so I haven't got any lines in my files.

So it would work, for example, in that method inside XMemcachedClient

```
public void setTimeoutExceptionThreshold(int timeoutExceptionThreshold) {
        if (timeoutExceptionThreshold <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Illegal timeoutExceptionThreshold value "
                            + timeoutExceptionThreshold);
        }
        if (timeoutExceptionThreshold < 100) {
            log.warn("Too small timeoutExceptionThreshold value may cause connections disconnect/reconnect frequently.");
        }
        this.timeoutExceptionThreshold = timeoutExceptionThreshold;
    }
```

It shows me **"Too small timeoutExceptionThreshold value may cause connections disconnect/reconnect frequently."** in my ${karaf.data}/log/spring/xmemcachedLog.log when **timeoutExceptionThreshold < 100**

Answer (score 0):

You should have a logback.xml somewhere which decide to show your log or not if you're on a java EE application.

Try to add this line of code into it:

```
<logger name="net.rubyeye.xmemcached" level="DEBUG"/>
```

It will activate DEBUG logs for all the classes in this package.
If it still doesn't work maybe you don't have the file in your classpath and you might have to add it in the jvm parameter.

Comment: It is a little bit incorrect, because I have that configuration in **org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg** . its file for apache-servicemix. Also, I've already line which you show. It looks like **log4j.logger.net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient=All, xmemcachedLog**